# There is a code I found that I need help understanding. It's very simple but I don't understand

Tags: python, python-2.7

It goes like this.

```
d = {"foo" : "bar"}
 
for key in d: 
  print d[key]
```

I don't understand how the output prints bar. There is nothing in the printing code that specifies the second element in the list.

Comment: It's not a list. It's a dictionary. `key` is `"foo"` and `d[key]` is `"bar"`.

Comment: Oh my bad but how is it accessing the second element without any code added

Comment: A dictionary is a collection of `key:value` pairs. There's only one pair in the dictionary.

Comment: It's not the second element. The dictionary contains one key and one value.

Comment: If you're learning Python for the first time, I suggest that you learn python-3 as python-2 has reached its EOL. What @khelwood says answers your question. Dictionaries contain key-value pairs. You can access the value of any key via `dict['key']`

Comment: Ohh I get it now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is a dictionary, not a list.

Within that dictionary, `foo` and `bar` represent a key-value pair (`foo` being the key, `bar` being the value).

You can access the keys, values, or both of a dictionary. In the code you've provided, the loop prints `bar` because it's the value that corresponds to the key `foo`.

`d['foo'] = 'bar'`

If you had more key-value pairs in the dictionary, it would print those as well. Let's say you had the following dictionary `d`:

```
d = {'foo': 'bar', 'monty': 'python', 'stack': 'overflow'}

for key in d: 
  print d[key]
```

would print

```
'bar'
'python'
'overflow'
```